# How can I remove KitKat's ActionBar Shadow?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Android 4.4 (Kitkat) introduced a dropshadow beneath the actionbar, and our designers would like for us to disable it if possible.

I know you can disable the shadow beneath the actionbar if using ActionBarSherlock, but we only support 4.0.3+ and don't want to introduce another library dependency if at all possible.

Is this possible? If yes: how do you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` to your App's theme definition.

**EDIT** I had `windowOverly` before, but it's actually `windowContentOverlay`

Comment: I tried adding it to my Activity as well as my ActionBar styles in styles.xml, but I still see the subtle drop shadow beneath the ActionBar

Comment: Did you apply the theme to your app in mainifest?

Answer (score 0):

DO THE FOLLOWING WITH THE Style

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
<...>
```

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
<..>
</style>
```

in order to remove the shadow add this

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: I stated that I *don't* want to use ActionBarSherlock.